# Unity creating a script for a square to move up on user input and fall down when there is no user input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a minigame similar to the fishing mechanism in Stardew Valley. I have two boundaries which are empty objects positioned at each end of a rectangle to keep the fish and the hook inside of the zone. When I run my script, the fish spawns at the bottom boundary and moves up instead of the position it is initially in. The hook generates at the bottom boundary and doesn't move upon user input.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FishingMiniGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Make the Egg move
    [Header("Fishing Area")]
    [SerializeField] Transform topBounds;
    [SerializeField] Transform bottomBounds;

    [Header("Fish Settings")]
    [SerializeField] Transform Fish;
    [SerializeField] float smoothMotion = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float fishTimeRandomizer = 3f;
    float fishPosition;
    float fishSpeed;
    float fishTimer;
    float fishTargetPosition;

    [Header("Hook Settinds")]
    [SerializeField] Transform Hook;
    [SerializeField] float HookSize = .18f;
    [SerializeField] float HookSpeed = .1f;
    [SerializeField] float HookGravity = .05f;
    float hookPosition;
    float hookPullVelocity;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveFish();
        MoveHook();
    }

    private void MoveHook()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //increase our pull velocity
            hookPullVelocity += HookSpeed * Time.deltaTime; //raises out hook
        }
        hookPullVelocity -= HookGravity * Time.deltaTime;

        hookPosition += hookPullVelocity;
        hookPosition = Mathf.Clamp(hookPosition, 0, 1); //keep the jook withon bounds
        Hook.position = Vector3.Lerp(bottomBounds.position, topBounds.position, hookPosition);
    }

    private void MoveFish()
    {
        //based on timer, pick random position
        //move fish to that position smoothly
        fishTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(fishTimer < 0)
        {
            //pick a new target position
            //reset timer
            fishTimer = Random.value * fishTimeRandomizer;
            fishTargetPosition = Random.value;
        }

        fishPosition = Mathf.SmoothDamp(fishPosition, fishTargetPosition, ref fishSpeed, smoothMotion);
        Fish.position = Vector3.Lerp(bottomBounds, topBounds, fishPosition);

    }
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure input should be performed during Update() and physics (including kinematics) during _FixedUpdate()_?

Comment: Alright i'll give it a try

Comment: Let us know how you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, making all the code in one script will be confuse. Try giving that fish its own script and game object.

Plus, take a look into [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). I think you are missundertanding how to use it. It takes 3 parameters with `a` being the original Vector3, so your current hook or fish position, `b` is your Vector3 target position, and `t` is the step or timestep. Should be delta or delta*someMultiplier.

What @MickyD said is also true, input should be performed during `Update()`, but that will not fix you code. `Update()`, `FixedUpdate()` and `LateUpdate()` are *kinda* the same but they run always in that order: Update -> FixedUpdate -> LateUpdate. So keep that in mind.

By the way, your gravity aplies every frame, so your hook is fighting against it even when you are lifting, resulting in half the force being neutralized. Making the gravity only apply on an else after your input will give you a much clear control of forces.

Comment: `and t is the step or timestep` -> No, Lerp expects a **factor** between `0` and `1` which is what OP already passes in, I think you confused that with `Vector3.MoveTowards` which rather expects a step